# Displaying an image from a json file in React Native

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, react-native

I am new to react native and creating a app that takes information from json and displays it as text and image.

I have stored the information in a mysql database and I am using php in order to get this information (as shown below)

```js
<?php
include 'DBConfig.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM EventsTable";

$result = $con->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows >0){
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $item = $row;
        $json = json_encode($item);
    }
} else {
    echo "No Results Found!";
}
echo $json;
$con->close();

?>
```

I then get the information from the file within react native and convert it to json.

I then want to be able to display the information in a text and pick out the file path for the images.

Here is my code.

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isLoading: true, 
          //ImageHolder: ''
        }
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://3b252dcf.ngrok.io/events.php')        
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson,
          }, () => {
            // In this block you can do something with new state.
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
      ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
          <View
          style={{
            height: .5,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
          }}
        />
        );
      }
      render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading){
          return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
              <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
          );
        }
        return (
          <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <FlatList style={{paddingTop: 30}}
              data={ this.state.dataSource }
              ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
            
              />   
          </View>
        );
      }
         _renderItem = ({item}) => {
         {
          return(
              <View style={styles.eventContainer}>
                  <Image source={{url:item.eventImage}}
                        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, paddingBottom: 10 }}
                />
              <View>
                  <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer}>{item.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.SermonByText}>{item.eventDate} - {item.eventTime}</Text>
              </View>
              </View>
          );
        }
      }
```

Here is the format of the json.

```js
  [{"id":"1","name":"Meeting","eventDate":"Tuesday","eventTime":"7:30pm","eventImage":"require('youth.png')"}}
```

I have added this line in order to this play the image.

```js
 <Image source={{url:item.eventImage}}
                        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, paddingBottom: 10 }}
                />
```

When I run the app on my iso simulator using Xcode the image does not display and I get the following warning.

[image: message]

How can I get the image to display

Comment: Have you already tried using `uri` instead of `url`?

Comment: yes, still have the same problem

Comment: Your JSON format is not valid, you need to parse it and make sure you have the right path to image.

And source={{url:item.eventImage}} must be source={{uri:item.eventImage}} if you get this uri from other resources than local, for local file source={tem.eventImage}

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem

Comment: still haven't been able to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `<Image source={require('path to file')} ...`